# FileInfo array won't show up in DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My aim is to habe a listing of all wave files in a specific folder in my webapplication project. So I tried this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("/alldata/wav/");
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] filelist = di.GetFiles("*.wav", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        DataList_filelist.DataSource = filelist;
        DataList_filelist.DataBind();
    }
```

Markup is:

```
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList_filelist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1">
        </asp:DataList>
```

But my DataList won't be displayed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I assume you have confirmed that filelist has data in?

Comment: @ Chris: yes, I did a debugging and made certain that my files were all in the FileInfo array.

Comment: Can you post the markup for DataList

Comment: @ V4Vendetta: I posted the markup above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding an Item Template which will let you display the required thing like

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("Name") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This should show you the name of the files in the array.

code might show up all the properties if you were to use GridView wherein you can `AutoGenerateColumns`

Comment: Thanks! The ItemTemplate was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're populating the datasource (i.e. you're looking in the right folder, and ASP has read permissions) Just skip the FileInfo[] array, and use the `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` as the datasource.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("/alldata/wav/");
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DataList_filelist.DataSource = di.GetFiles("*.wav");
DataList_filelist.DataBind();
```